# Windows 7 features on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008

I just started a new job and they have me running on Server 2008 (most likely because a lot of work is done in VMs).  Some of my co-workers have a windows 7 look and feel even though they're running on Server 2008 that I'd like to get too.  It seems that you have install "Desktop Experience" to enable the Windows 7 aero theme, but much more important to me is the taskbar with grouping of windows (without the text) that exists in Windows 7, but especially the snapping of windows to the sides and top to maximize.  I've gotten so used to this that it seems extremely tedious to go back to doing it the old way.  Does anyone know how to enable these features on my system?  I have already installed Desktop Experience, like I said, enabled the Aero theme and turned on all the visual effects in Performance settings.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Server 2008 or Server 2008 R2? R2 is the only one that will have the task bar grouping feature like Win7, non-R2 will be set up like Vista.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check for R2.  I know it's Windows Server Standard 2007 Service Pack 2 (I'm guessing that's 2008)  I've installed the feature and everything, but when i go to the display options, it's not showing the windows 7 options.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go to Start -> Right click on Computer and choose Properties. In the first section (Windows edition), it should say 'Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard' if it is R2 Standard Edition. If it doesn't say R2, it's not R2.

Answer (score 0):

With Server 2008 **R2** once Aero is running all of the features of Aero Snap (Moving an open window to the sides), Aero Peek, Aero shake, and Jump lists are enabled.

None of these features are available on Windows Server 2008 (non-R2) without 3rd party software.

In case aero isn't running for you currently, the guide here is perfect: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-enable-aero-on-windows-server-2008-x64-and-x86-32-bit/

With Server 2008 non-R2 you can install the beta version of Aerosnap.de 
to regain some of this functionality.

You may find further helpful information here: 
http://www.win2008workstation.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=5&sid=0b99430aad179502eb589a1c756ffdc9

I am not affiliated with any of the links in this posting.

Good Luck.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check for R2. I know it's Windows Server Standard 2007 Service Pack 2 (I'm guessing that's 2008) I've installed the feature and everything, but when i go to the display options, it's not showing the windows 7 options. Thanks in advance.